# Is it possible to change the order of a div depending onchange function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am working on jquerymobiles.
I have to change the order of displaying div depending on change of value in select box

### html

```
<select class="sel">
      <option value="1">one</option>
       <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
         </select>

          <div class="first">first</div>
             <div class="second">second</div>
```

### jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".sel" ).change(function() {

        var val=$(this).val();
              if(val == 1)
            {

            $(".first").show();
                  $(".second").show();
                   }
         if(val == 2)
            {
           $(".second").show();
            $(".first").show();
                   }
          if(val == 3)
           {
       $(".first").show();
               $(".second").hide();
           }
        });
       });
```

I have to change the order of displaying div depending on the change of value.

If the user select option "two" then output should be.like this :

```
 second

 first
```

If the user select option "one" then output should be

```
first

 second
```

if the user select option "three" then it should display:

```
 first
```

Please any one help me.
Here is [js fiddledemo](http://jsfiddle.net/PriyankaPatil/2Ghqr/)

Comment: you need to write separate HTMLs for all onchange functions and append/replace them according to your need.

Comment: What's the problem it's working as you wish...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ghqr/12/)**

If you have multiple if conditions, always use `switch()` cases

Use

- **[.prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)** : Insert content before. Though this gives to one time solution. You have to use `insertBefore()`
- **[.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)** : Remove set of matched elements.

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".sel").change(function () {
         switch (this.value) {
             case '1':
                 $('.first').insertBefore('.second');
                 break;
             case '2':
                 $('.second').insertBefore('.first');
                 break;
             case '3':
                 $('.second').hide();
                 break;
         }

     });
 });
```

Comment: It's not working fine. If you select 1 - 2 - 1 divs mess up. That's an example, you should use insertBefore() and show() at the beginning of any case because in case 3 you hide one of them.

Comment: Yes, I knew that. It was a one time solution. Also I had suggested `insertBefore()` to OP. Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes you did suggest but .prependTo() is not an option here because it inserts content inside a selector at the very beginning of it not before it as you say ".prependTo() : Insert content before." Code is better now! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following strategy: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ghqr/5/

Explanation:

When you encounter a situation where you want to reorder the DOM elements, we need to reattach them in the dom, you can pick up the element and then place them where you want to.

So here, I've simply picked `first` and `second` and placed them accordingly in a container.

As you can see, I have encapsulated the 'first' and 'second' `div` in a container called `content`.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="first">first</div>
    <div class="second">second</div>
</div>
```

I have modified the JavaScript to the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".sel").change(function () {

         var val = $(this).val();
         if (val == 1) {
            $('.content').append($(".first")).append($('.second'));
             $(".first").show();
             $(".second").show();
         }
         if (val == 2) {
             $('.content').append($('.second')).append($(".first"));
             $(".second").show();
             $(".first").show();
         }
         if (val == 3) {
             $(".first").show();
             $(".second").hide();
         }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

the simples way is to use before():

http://jsfiddle.net/2Ghqr/11/

```
      $( ".sel" ).change(function() {

        var value=$(this).val();
            if(value==1){
                $('.second').before($('.first'));
            }
            if(value==2){
                $('.first').before($('.second'));
            }
            if(value==3){
                $('.second').before($('.first'));
            }
        });
```